# Can I ask for a comparison of several possible approaches?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a scenario which I need to implement in Groovy/VBA, but I am stuck on how to do it. I have a couple of approaches in mind but do not know if they will work or if there is a better way.

Can I ask this question on Stack Overflow? If not is there any other site on Stack Exchange where I can ask this?

Comment: Yes, but only if you narrow it down. If you ask "how should I do this", you will get hit with "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based". Your best bet is to outline all the differences between them, or just pick one and ask for direction from there.